# Filtering out field that don't exist

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on improving my code and I have a question regarding queries of type Query. Some of these Object have a field called ended_at, while others don't. I'm unable to use where('ended_at', isEqualTo: null) because the ended_at field is created after the object is created. Is there a way to filter out the objects that do not have the ended_at field before calling snapshot()? I want to be able to only retrieve the objects that don't have the ended_at field to avoid errors.

I have tried using the contains method, but that only works after calling snapshot() and I'm trying to avoid that to improve performance. I'm also not sure how to use hasField() or containsKey() without calling snapshot(). I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve using where() since the field ended_at may or may not exist in the queried objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to get documents that have the `ended_at` field, no matter what value the field has, you can use a `where("ended_at", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: null)` condition on your query.

This *excludes* the documents without the `ended_at` field, as those don't exist in the index, but then *includes* all documents with the field (regardless of its values) as `null` is the first value in all ordering as shown in the documentation on [ordering of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering).